# Не выполняется блок else в условии, когда if выдает false

Tags: c++

```
void del(ListNode* ge_info, char* n) {
    Node* begin = ge_info->start_p;
    Node* cur_next = nullptr;
    Node* cur_prev = nullptr;
    do {
        if (!strcmp(n, begin->name)) {
            cur_next = begin->next;
            cur_prev = begin->prev;
            delete(begin);
            if (cur_prev != nullptr) {
                cur_prev->next = cur_next;
            } else {
                ge_info->start_p == cur_next;
            }

            if (cur_next != nullptr) {
                cur_next->prev = cur_prev;
            } else {
                ge_info->end_p == cur_prev;
            }
            break;
        }
        else {
            begin = begin->next;
        }
    } while (begin->next != ge_info->end_p);
}
```

if (cur_prev != nullptr) в отладке выдает false, тут все верно, раз if выдает false должен выполниться блок else, но он его пропускает и переходит сразу к if (cur_next != nullptr).

Comment: а с какими параметрами вы компилировали? Возможно вы выставили уровень оптимизации отличный от 0, в результате чего выполнение кода будет происходить в несколько другой последовательности, чем написано в коде. Однако блок все равно будет выполнен

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch параметры никакие не выставлял, компилирую тем, что мне предлагает Visual Studio, все настройки дефолтные

Comment: на будущее: избегайте подобного разъяснения. Оно вообще ничего не скажет большинству программистов. Ну просто потому, что помимо VS есть и другие IDE, а некоторый так и без IDE обходятся (я в их числе). К тому же есть разные версии VS и, я уверен, в них могут фигурировать разные дефолтные настройки. Про то, что большинство IDE имеют разные режимы сборки (как минимум Debug и Release) я вообще молчу. То что вы не знаете что за вас делает инструмент (тем более настолько важное как параметры компиляции) - говорит не в ваше пользу. Потрудитесь узнать флаги компиляции с которыми производите сборку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ge_info->start_p == cur_next`

Бессмысленная операция сравнения, компилятор может её смело удалить.

Думаю, что подразумевалось присваивание:

`ge_info->start_p = cur_next`

Comment: Господи, я минут 40 не мог это обнаружить... Спасибо большое::))

Comment: @АндрейПетров на будущее: чтобы избегать таких проблем включайте максимальный уровень варнингов (`Wall` для `gcc` и `clang`) - такие проблемы на глаз трудно обнаружить (я, например, и сам не заметил), зато компилятор их находит на раз-два. А еще лучше в довесок использовать статический анализтор (вроде `cppcheck`)